# Why is multiplication of numbers with floating point inside a loop isn't as precise as outside of it?

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point, precision, pow

I was writing a program to calculate `sin(x)` with `x` in `[0, 1]`, using Taylor series that include raising some of its terms to a certain power. Since I'm new to C, I decided to write my own `pow()` function just to practice. But then I noticed that my program doesn't calculate the sine function correctly. Upon an examination, I discovered that raising a number to a power in a loop doesn't produce the same result as simple straightforward multiplication ...v * v * v...

Here's my `powr()` function and difference in results:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

double powr(double base, int power)
{
    if (power == 0) {
        base = 1;
    } else if (power > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
            base *= base;
        }
    } else {
        // power is negative.
    }
    printf("In loop number to a power of 3: %lf\n", base);
    double hard_coded = 0.99 * 0.99 * 0.99;
    printf("Out of loop number to a power of 3: %lf\n", hard_coded); 

    return base;
}

int main(void)
{
    double num = 0.99;
    double num_to_power = powr(num, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In loop number to a power of 3: 0.960596
Out of loop number to a power of 3: 0.970299
```

**0.960596 and 0.970299 may not look that different, but with smaller values an error becomes even bigger.
Why is that and how can I solve it?**

**Also**, I just noticed that if I take small values like `0.123` and raise them to a power of `6`, for example. I have an output like `0.000000`. I understand that it's just too small to show up. But how can I print an a floating-point number that has more than 6 after point numbers? I've tries `long double`, didn't work either.

Comment: The calculation `0.99 * 0.99 * 0.99` will very likely be optimized and done by the compiler itself, rather than done at run-time.

Comment: So, no way to do it precisely within a loop then?(

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph you can use width specifier with printf, for example `%.40lf` will print 40 decimal places.

Comment: @lil_robo "writing a program to calculate sin(x)" --> Using a power calculation for each term is a weak approach.  Instead, calculate each term based on the prior term.  Instead of a `pow(x, n)`, use `term = term * x * x * ...`.  IOWs, to achieve your `sin()`, `double powr(double base, int power)` is not needed at all.

Comment: "how can I print an a floating-point number that has more than 6 after point numbers?" --> use `"%g"` instead of `"%f"`.

Answer (score 6):

Your loop calculation is wrong. The `base *= base;` line will, on each loop, multiply the 'accumulated' value by the value that has been **modified** on the previous loop, rather than by the *original* value (as it should).

You need to store the passed `base` value and use that saved value as the multiplier on each loop:

```c
double powr(double base, int power)
{
    double saved = base;
    if (power == 0) {
        base = 1;
    }
    else if (power > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
            base *= saved;
        }
    }
    else {
        // power is negative.
    }

    printf("In loop number to a power of 3: %lf\n", base);
    double hard_coded = 0.99 * 0.99 * 0.99;
    printf("Out of loop number to a power of 3: %lf\n", hard_coded);

    return base;
}
```

The two output vales will then be equivalent:

```
In loop number to a power of 3: 0.970299
Out of loop number to a power of 3: 0.970299
```

Comment: In your test case, you get `0.99 * 0.99 * 0.99 * 0.99` (note the extra multiplication).

Comment: Probably better to use `saved *= base` and `return saved` rather than modify the parameter (not forgetting to initialise `saved = 0.0`)?

Comment: @Andrew Possibly. But I was working on the MNC principle (Minimum Necessary Change); and the passed `base` is only a copy, anyway.

Comment: He actually wrote a function that returns base to the 2^n power where n is the power parameter.

Comment: @carce-bo Maybe actually 2^(n-1) ... but, yeah.

Comment: @Andrew  "(not forgetting to initialise `saved = 0.0`)" --> Hmmm, `saved *= base` will then be 0.0.

Comment: Yeah... took too long to realise my error so couldn't edit it!

Answer (score 4):

First, your loop does not calculate what you need:

```
for (int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
    base *= base;
}
```

In you case you are calculating:

1. first iteration `base *= base` will give `base=0.99*0.99=0.9801`
2. second iteration `base *= base` will give `base=0.9801*09801=0.96059601`

By accumulating previous result over time you are calculating `base^(2^(exp-1))`. No surprise then. For exponentiation a simple loop like this will make it:

```
result = base;
for (int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
    result *= base;
}
```

There exists a simple fast exponentiation that use squaring if you want to make it faster (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Second, the *hard coded* version can be computed by the compiler in any other way, and as floating point computation is very sensible to rounding errors, the result may be different.

Comment: @AdrianMole changed.